# binding in datatemplate cause an error 'Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element'

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

1. When both `place1`(TextBlock in mainwindow) and `place2`(MergedDictionaries in app.xaml) exist, cause an error:'Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element'
2. When one or both of `place1` and `place2` are commented out, the error is not displayed
3. so why?

source is [here](https://github.com/yibei333/ErrorData/raw/main/WpfBindingError.zip)

MainWindow.cs

```xml
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <!--place1-->
        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Foo">
            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Bar">Hello</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                <!--error position-->
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=Bar,Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Button.ContentTemplate>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

App.Xaml

```xml
<Application x:Class="Demo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--place2-->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Demo.Lib;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Your reported error is not reproducible using your code. You should never merge the Generic.xaml file into the App.xaml or any other ResourceDictionary. The Generic.xaml must only contain default styles targeting your custom controls. WPF will resolve those Styles correctly by trying to find the Generic.xaml dictionary located in the assembly that defines the control. You only waste resources and degrade performance for nothing.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that commenting out the irrelevant top level TextBlock or irrelevant resources defined in App.xaml would have any impact on the binding engine trying to resolve a Binding inside a DataTemplate. It's not possible.

Comment: Maybe a Clean and Rebuild will help to resolve the issue. Or your code is missing something elementary in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: you mean i should bring all control style to Generic.aml file,instead split to single file

Comment: No you can have  a default Style in a dedicated file per control and merge each into the Generic.xaml. But it is not necessary to merge the Generic.xaml into the App.xaml. It even does worse. WPF will find Generic.xaml without merging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by not merging as @BionicCode say 'it is not necessary to merge the Generic.xaml into the App.xaml'